# get text with index number and then compare with the expected text

Tags: ruby, automation, ui-automation, calabash-android, testautomationfx

I need to write a method which will get text with the help of index number from popup and then i need to compare with the expected text
i.e i need to verify expected plan name is displayed at the bottom of the popup box

[image: snapshot of the pop up box]

Answer (score 0):

Setting the correct id for the query (which you can get by doing on calabash console the command `query("*", :id)`) on code below should do the trick. If you can't use id try to get another component property (like Android component by using  `query("*")` ) and set the query inside the`get_text` calls.

```
def get_text(query)
  query(plan_query, :text).first
end

def text_equals(text, expected_text)
  unless text == expected_text
    fail "#{text} not equal to #{expected_text}"
  end
end

def verify_plan(index, expected_text)
  plan_text = get_text("* id:'PLAN_TEXTS_ID' index:#{index}") # Can change 'id:...'' by Android class if plan does not have id
  expected_text = get_text("* id:'BOTTOM_PLAN_ID'") # Same as above
  text_equals(plan_text, expected_text)
end
```